# SQLIte : Query to find all keywords in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I am working with SQLite. I need to know a query that retrieves all KEYWORDS in SQLite. Ex:

```
For Oracle:  select * from v$reserved_words 
For MySQL:  select * from mysql.help_keyword
```

Above query will show all keywords in the corresponding database. Like this, I need a query for SQLite. Anyone knows please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to dynamically retrieve the list of reserved words, with a system table or a pragma.

The documentation lists the (currently) 124 [keywords](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html). It seems that the actual list also depends on the compile-time options.